# No response of button in the headerView of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

The design is that there is a return button in the headerView, but I can not get any response of the return button.

Here is some description of my code: I add a delegate in my headerView, so when I click the button in headerView, the UIViewController can return to the front one. I define a class to be headerView, and in this class I add the return button like this :

```
    _returnButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 20, 16, 20)];
    _returnButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    _returnButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [_returnButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"return.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self addSubView:_returnButton];
```

Then in the UIViewController, I create an instance of my headerView and add it to my UITableView:

```
ThemeHeader *headerView = [[ThemeHeader alloc] init];
headerView.delegate = self;
headerView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[headerView updateIfNeeded];
```

In the function updateIfNeeded, I add the target to my headerView, just like this:

```
- (void)updateIfNeeded {
   NSLog(@"test delegate");
   if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(return:)]) {
       NSLog(@"succeed");
       [_returnButton addTarget:self.delegate action:@selector(return:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }

}
```

I can see the log "test delegate" and "succeed", but when I click the return button, it seems nothing happens, and I can not see any log. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Where is the UITableView?

Comment: Try to `addTarget` in your viewController like this `[headerView_returnButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

Comment: Check that _returnButton allocated when you add target and that table view not intercepts touches

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify

[**self.contentView** addSubView:_returnButton];